# Как переписать запрос под гугл скрипт

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Мне нужно геокодировать координаты в адрес, но гугл скрипт не принимает код, пишет fetch - такая команда не найдена. На локалке все работает, данные вытаскиваю, но мне нужно чтобы в гугл редакторе этот код заработал. Если есть кто знает что нужно сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Я предполагаю, что нужно переписать запрос другим способом - UrlFetchApp.fetch

```js
var url = "https://suggestions.dadata.ru/suggestions/api/4_1/rs/geolocate/address";
var token = "IPI KEY";
var query = { lat: 55.878, lon: 37.653 };

var options = {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Token " + token
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(query)
}

fetch(url, options)
.then(response => response.text())
.then(result => console.log(result))
.catch(error => console.log("error", error));
```

Comment: а что такое гугл скрипт?

Comment: Google apps script. Редактор онлайн

Answer (score 0):

Можете сделать так:

```js
try {
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  
  const result = response.getContentText();
  
  console.log(result);
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```